# Coloured dot cipher

Tags: cipher

I, as a curious being, stumbled upon a page which had a hidden dot cipher in it.
Part of the console states:

> [...] we left you a little message in the dots of the footer

*(Source: segment.com)*

The footer contains this image:
https://d1gi394wp2tyv2.cloudfront.net/site-public/2.66.17-444-g51d17d0/files/dots-3d885a6982.svg
(There are also almost white dots - be careful)

EDIT: Uploaded with black background
[image: Dot cipher with black background]

I wonder what those dots mean...

Comment: What's "as a curious" mean?

Comment: @YoutRied I think you're misparsing it. "as a curious being" = "as a being who is curious".

Comment: @Fareth McCaughan oops I missed that "being part

Comment: Tip for the less technically inclined: svg files are human-readable. You can open it in Notepad and see the precise coordinates and color of each dot, without having to futz about with the eyedropper tool in Paint. There may also be additional clues in the file that aren't apparent in the visual rendering. For instance, I notice that there are three distinct <g> groups that the dots are categorized in, each having a different way of `transform`ing the dots.